# Graduate Recruitment weekend: faculty interview - research area mismatch

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, interview

I have been invited to graduate recruitment weekend at a school (PhD applicant in biomedical imaging). I have been told about an interview scheduled with one of the faculty members.

But my background does not match at all with the faculty's work. What to  expect in the interview? How can I use the opportunity to my benefit/admit? This faculty is doing some amazing work, I am totally impressed by it, but I just have zero background in it. Any suggestions/advice?

Comment: Do you mean that your background doesn't match with this _one_ faculty member's research or that it doesn't match with anyone's?

Comment: My background does not match with the faculty who has shortlisted me for interview.

Comment: In general there are other professors in the department whose research aligns with mine. But this school sends grad recruitment weekend invites based on individual faculty recommendations. So basically, I was recommended for Grad weekend by a faculty whose research area does not align with that of mine, not even close.

Comment: Is this the *only* interview you have there? Or does the invitation to interview include meetings with other professors as well?

Comment: Zero background or zero interest?  I'm in mathematics, and an average applicant would have approximately zero background in research area of most faculty members anyway.  So that would be quite normal.  Maybe this is field dependent.

Comment: At my institution, recruitment weekend is for people who have been admitted. The “interviews” are meetings to convince you to join the department. So your question title and question text are confusing to me.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, this is the only interview I have, with the professor I mentioned about and the lab members of the same professor.

Comment: @Dawn At this institute the admit depends on how individual interviews will go during Grad recruitment weekend.

Comment: @ssquidd I would say zero background. The overview of research done by this faculty seems very interesting.

Answer (score 7):

Don't make assumptions. Perhaps they really do see something in your background that they think is valuable to their own work. Maybe that would appeal to you, or not. But have the conversation first, and keep an open mind.

However, it might just be that the faculty as a whole divided up the interview task so that every one participates and everyone gets an interview. They might even recommend you to a colleague if there is a real mismatch. You say they "shortlisted" you but it may have been something more clerical than an actual choice. Don't read too much into the description of how you were chosen.

But there is no reason to give up your goals if they lie elsewhere. You probably don't need to accept a long term research relationship that you wouldn't find interesting. If you know of another professor, by name, you could even mention them as someone whose work appeals to you.

But, more important, if what they do is "important and interesting" then background can be developed. In the US there is a lot of opportunity for that, but less so in some other places.

Comment: Or even the best faculty match was busy that day

Comment: I finally had my interview with the professor I mentioned. Beforehand, I read about his work and had some questions in mind related to the work. 
During the meeting, the professor kept on suggesting other professors who might be more suited with my background and gave their contact details. I tried to steer the conversation to his research again and again, but it didn't seem to work. The prof also asked me about other schools I have applied to. He himself also read out the list of professors I mentioned in my application. Graduate weekend is over and I am afraid that I didn't make the cut.

Comment: He is giving you good advice. If he recommends another colleague, then that person is probably better suited to your skill set. This happened to me, actually, in a somewhat different context. I approached a professor who said he couldn't take me on, but recommended me to one of the top professors in the department who did. It turned out to be a gigantic win.